# Как парсить XML со стандартным компонентом?

Tags: xml, delphi

Ни разу не парсил XML. Объясните вкратце, как из XML отпарсить в таблицу, обязательно со стандартным компонентом. Или пример покажите, или может толковую документацию дадите.

Answer (score 1):

Пример статьи где используется стандартный компонент XML
[Cсыль](http://parsing-and-i.blogspot.com/2008/08/xml-delphi.html)